# Unable to start hotspot in access point mode in Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom, ap-hotspot

I am unable to start hotspot in access point mode in my Kubuntu 16.04.1 version. I have installed it recently and is fully updated. My wireless driver is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

and the result of command *iw list* is:

```
Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 1
    max scan IEs length: 0 bytes
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Supported Ciphers:
            * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
            * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
            * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
            * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
            * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
             * IBSS
             * managed
    Band 1:
            Bitrates (non-HT):
                    * 1.0 Mbps
                    * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                    * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                    * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                    * 6.0 Mbps
                    * 9.0 Mbps
                    * 12.0 Mbps
                    * 18.0 Mbps
                    * 24.0 Mbps
                    * 36.0 Mbps
                    * 48.0 Mbps
                    * 54.0 Mbps
            Frequencies:
                    * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 2484 MHz [14] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
    Band 2:
            Bitrates (non-HT):
                    * 6.0 Mbps
                    * 9.0 Mbps
                    * 12.0 Mbps
                    * 18.0 Mbps
                    * 24.0 Mbps
                    * 36.0 Mbps
                    * 48.0 Mbps
                    * 54.0 Mbps
            Frequencies:
                    * 5170 MHz [34] (disabled)
                    * 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5190 MHz [38] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5210 MHz [42] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5230 MHz [46] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 2061 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 2061 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 2061 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 2061 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5500 MHz [100] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 2061 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5520 MHz [104] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 2061 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5540 MHz [108] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 2061 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5560 MHz [112] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 2061 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5580 MHz [116] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 2061 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5600 MHz [120] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 2061 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5620 MHz [124] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 2061 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5640 MHz [128] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 2061 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5660 MHz [132] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 2061 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5680 MHz [136] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 2061 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5700 MHz [140] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 2061 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5745 MHz [149] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5765 MHz [153] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5785 MHz [157] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5805 MHz [161] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5825 MHz [165] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5920 MHz [184] (disabled)
                    * 5940 MHz [188] (disabled)
                    * 5960 MHz [192] (disabled)
                    * 5980 MHz [196] (disabled)
                    * 6000 MHz [200] (disabled)
                    * 6020 MHz [204] (disabled)
                    * 6040 MHz [208] (disabled)
                    * 6060 MHz [212] (disabled)
                    * 6080 MHz [216] (disabled)
    Supported commands:
             * set_interface
             * new_key
             * join_ibss
             * set_pmksa
             * del_pmksa
             * flush_pmksa
             * connect
             * disconnect
    software interface modes (can always be added):
    interface combinations are not supported
    Device supports scan flush
```

How do I get my wireless driver to support AP mode? I can start hotspot in ad-hoc mode but it is not detected in any devices except one it is hosted from. And I am unable to start hotspot in access point mode. How do I start hotspot in access point mode?

Answer (score 0):

In the data you posted, under "Supported interface modes," AP mode is not listed. The proprietary driver *bcmwl-kernel-source* does not support AP mode.

I am unaware of any other driver that is available that correctly drives your device *and* supports AP mode.

For reference, here is the corresponding output from another device that does support AP mode.

```
Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
```

Comment: Does that mean that I can't create access point hotspot in my laptop? Because I can create hotspot in my Windows 10. What is the possible issue with my driver?

Comment: Can you at least suggest any source or person who can help me with it? I really like Kubuntu os and it is necessary for me to make the hotspot work.

Comment: I know of no such resource. The hardware/driver/os combination are not designed nor capable of doing what you are asking. You could always just get a different device.